# How can i get authorization code from tiktok api

Tags: php, tiktok

I need help. I develop php rest api to get followers count of my tiktok account from tiktok api. Here is a way to call tiktok api from server without user interaction with tiktok login form ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need the user's permission to access account data (including the scope "user.info.stats"), so there's no way to use the API w/out the login form.

You can, however, try to get the approximate follower count from the website (as this information is public). All the data is nicely packed inside

```
<script id="SIGI_STATE" type="application/json">
```

on the about page and can be parsed quite easily.

Since you're asking for your own account: Why don't you want to log in to give authorization? You only have to do this once.